# Too Many Container Components in Redux (n number , where n is not known), worried about performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I m building a web application where, it will have posts, user can comments on those posts and posts can have replies, and i have `<Newsfeed />`  Container component to fetch all posts through api(i m using redux for data store), but the problem is that now i will have to pass too much data to sub components, so i will thinking that i should create container components `<CommentListContainer />` and `<ReplyListContainer />` so in `<Post />` component i will have to pass basic post info and then post can have `<CommentListContainer postId={post_id}
/>` inside it, and `<Comment />` can have `<ReplyListContainer commentId={comment_id}/>` because **my data is normalized in redux** 
ex:-

```
entities : {
    "users" : {
        "byIds" : {
            "id" : { 
                // basic info
                "comments" : [4, 5, 6],
            }
        }  
    },
    "comments" : {
        "byIds" : {
            "id" : {
                "replies" : [1, 2, 3] // etc
            } 
        }
    }
    ... same replies
}
```

so it should be easy, but i m worried about too many container components :) because newsfeed can have 50 posts, and if each post have 5 comments, then there is going to be 250 container components, will there be any performance issue there because of too many container components ?, but the advantage of this approach is that is very simple to implement, so i want to know which one is better and in big application (this is common senerio for most applications), how they does it ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Dan Abramov, you will have better performance connect()-ing more containers to the redux store: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/419#issuecomment-129188175

Comment: Dan created Redux.  I'm a current Redux maintainer, and yes, this is the correct answer.  Also see [the Redux FAQ entry on connecting multiple components](https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree), and my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/).